# I have an app that I'm building using a finance API that works but can't break down the JSON response to get the data into powerapps

Tags: json, powerapps, power-automate

I have set everything up so far (API request, parse json and respones) and can see my data in the response section in power automate, but when I go to powerapps to extract the data, I can't seem to pull it out because of the crazy JSON output. Also, I did this process before and had no problems with a different API (alpha vantage). Thanks

I tried several data pull logics in powerapps by filtering but none worked.

Comment: Impossible to help without more information.

Comment: as mentioned provide us with more details, what error you get what is your json output and so on.